# Expose docker deamon from wsl to windows

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemd

With latest update for windows11 and wsl, now we are able to tu use systemd on wsl (yay)

So the first thing I've done was to enable it and install docker following [those](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) instuctions on my ubuntu 22.04 distro, and it works fine.

Second part of my evil plan was to expose docker daemon from wsl to windows and install docker-cli from windows too (I don't need desktop version)

So I made those changes to `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` (add `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` to dockerd conf)
[image]

on windows host add `DOCKER_HOST` env
[image]

but if I try to run any docker cmd thst's what I get
[image]

Any suggestion? I'm missing something?

Comment: The `dockerd -H` option you propose is a major security disaster: on native Linux it would allow anyone on the same network as your host to trivially root the machine.  Are you _sure_ you want it?  I try to avoid systemd, but does it accept PNG files like what you've included in `/lib/systemd` (or can you [edit] the question to include the text of the file instead)?